# Clarification of solution set of a system of linear equations in three variables.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reviewing Jordan Canonical form:

I have a situation where I have two linearly independent eigenvectors for a 3x3 matrix and I am trying to find the third.

In the example it is saying that by solving the following:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 &0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}     \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x  \\y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} $$

we will get the solution set $\,\,x \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + y \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

But for whatever reason I am not understanding why that is the solution set. Looking for some explanation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get that the solutions are $\{(x,y,-y)+(0,0,1)|x,y\in\Bbb R\}$.  Just back substitute to get the solution to the associated homogeneous system; and note that $(0,0,1)$ is a particular solution.

That is, it's correct.  The general form for the solution of a linear system is $\text{general solution}=\{\text{particular solution} + \text{elements of the kernel}\}$.

Comment: I am rusty with my linear algebra so forgive me, if I carry out the multiplication for the system of linear equations I get $y+z=1$ or rather get $x=x, y = 1 - z, z=z$. And so I am not connecting the dots to how that is the solution set.

Comment: You get that $x$ can be anything; and that $y=-z$, for the kernel of the matrix on the left.  Also, note that $(0,0,1)$ is a particular solution of the actual system.  Are you familiar with this result?

Comment: $(0,0,1)$ just picks off the third column of the matrix, which is indeed $(1,0,0)$.  So it's a particular solution.  For the kernel part, replace the $(1,0,0)$ on the right with $0$.

Comment: My write-up could be a little better.  Sorry.  The point is that every solution is of the form $v+w$, where $v$ is a particular solution and $w$ is a solution of the associated homogeneous system;  that is the system gotten by replacing the right hand side with zero.

Comment: I vaguely recall learning about particular solutions but its been a while. What I recall is getting an augmented matrix into RREF then setting free variables to zero, so if I were to do that I would have $(0,1,0)$ as my particular solution I believe, so I guess I don't immediately see why this example has $(0,0,1)$ as the particular solution.

Comment: They both are actually.  But you only need one.  If the kernel is nontrivial, there are more than one particular solution.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Do you have some insight on how they got this one of $(0,0,1)$. In the example it 'magically' works out that this particular solution $(0,0,1)$ will be the third eigenvector needed for the Jordan canonical form, so I'd like to understand how they arrived at this particular solution.

Comment: Like I said, you will soon know, if you don't already, that the standard basis vectors give back the corresponding columns of the matrix.  So, the reason both of $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ work is that they give back, respectively, the second and third column.  Those two columns happen to be the same, and are also the same as the RHS.